# Is it possible for SLDS-Backdrop to gray out only current tab and not the entire screen?

Tags: lightning, lightning-web-components, lightning-experience, lightning-design-system, slds

I am using SLDS-Backdrop CSS to gray out the background while a progress bar runs. This CSS class grays out the entire screen till the progress completes itself, which the business doesn't want, as it keeps the whole screen occupied for long durations and hence hampering productivity. See below:

[image: Entire screen gets grayed - read only]

I was wondering if there is a way to accomplish this, to make the backdrop effective only inside the tab, while the rest of the lightning application is available for use.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: I don't believe so. You'll need to define your own CSS. However, you cannot use absolute positioning since this is disallowed by Salesforce for security reasons. In terms of the processing you have in progress, my concern (if you retain access to parts of the page) is that were the user to move away from the tab/page then any processing orchestrated by your client-side LWC code would be stopped. If your LWC is simply reflecting progress of some back-end processing that will not be interrupted, then it should be OK if they move away of course, but your question doesn't provide this detail.

Comment: @PhilW The orchestrated process doesn't really need the user to stick right with! It essentially is the progress of an apex batch-run in the background, submitted from the component, so a user can't really do much to hamper it. All I expect is that the user doesn't have the access to the component while a batch is running, to avoid multiple requests to clog the queue, while the rest of the lightning application is available to work on.

Comment: How about just disabling the "submission" button when there's a batch on-going?